# How to add multiple images to svg in D3 (quantity based on value in dataset)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to apply an image to svg multiple times, with the quantity based on value from a dataset? I'm trying to do smth like this:

dataset:

```
var dataset = [{"attribute": "att1", "data": "5"}, {"attribute": "att2", "data": "10"}]
```

### SVG:

att1

$$$$$

att2

### $$$$$$$$$$

...with $ being an image.

Below code adds an image based on number of attribute occurencies instead of the "data". So I get 2 images. How to get 2 sets of images with 5 and 10 occurencies?

```
var w = 300;
var h = 300;
var p = 20;

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.style("border", "1px solid black");

var img = svg.selectAll("image")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("svg:image")
.attr("x", function(d,i) {return (i * 10);})
.attr("width", 50)
.attr("height", 50)
.style("border", "1px solid black")
.attr("xlink:href", "images/xyz.png");
```

Comment: you need to do a loop. So for each one,m loop through i; where i is equal to the value of dataset, and append an image on each iteration

Comment: @thatOneGuy There is no need for a loop here, check my answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado technically it's still looping though ;)

Comment: Well, following that reasoning, almost everything is a loop at machine code! :) What I mean by *loop* of course is an explicit JavaScript loop which, in a D3 code, is normally unnecessary and shows that the coder is not using idiomatic D3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `d3.range()` to set the number of repetitions.

In this solution, I'm binding the data to the parent groups...

```
var groups = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
```

... and, in the image selection, I'm using an array whose length is determined by the property `data` in the dataset:

```
var images = groups.selectAll("bar")
    .data(d => d3.range(d.data))
```

Check the demo:

```js
var dataset = [{
  image: "http://icons.webpatashala.com/icons/Blueberry-Basic-Icons/Png/rss-icon.PNG",
  data: 5
}, {
  image: "http://www.ucdmc.ucdavis.edu/global/images/icons/instagram-32x32.png",
  data: 3
}, {
  image: "http://www.axadledirect.com/assets/images/icons/share/32x32/google.png",
  data: 8
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var groups = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(10," + (10 + i * 40) + ")");

var images = groups.selectAll("bar")
    .data(d => d3.range(d.data))
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 35);
    })
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().image
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'm not yet sure how exactly, but it works. PS what's the => in your notation? A shortcut for function?

Comment: Yes, it's an arrow function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: One more question: do you have any suggestion why this doesn't apply y transformation to the g groups? the 3 groups re still on eon another. var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0" + function(d,i) {return i*100} + ")";

Comment: I was about to answer here, but I saw you just posted another question.